# Get web page HTML with WebClient

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the source code of "`https://codal.ir`",
but the result isn't equal with the source code in inspect in Google Chrome.

Here's my code:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
    {
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://codal.ir");
    }
}
```

Comment: The "source code" you inspect in Chrome is likely modified with Javascript. There are numerous questions about scraping single page applications and the like, which should have the answer you seek if that's the case.

Comment: To view the source code of a page in Chrome (on Windows) you need to press `Ctrl+u`. This is the page source before JS runs and modifies the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just need the source code of a **static web page**

```
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string urlAddress = "https://codal.ir";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                string data = readStream.ReadToEnd(); // Data variable here
                readStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your time but your answer only in html body returns some script like this: 
<script src=\"/ScriptResource.axd?d =daKfEmtpF96......>
but I want html code after the execution of these scripts.